# Why am I getting an eslint error (Unexpected token :) when adding types to methods

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, eslint

I'm using vue3 and eslint in my application, and for some reason, the eslint keeps giving me the following error `Unexpected token:` when I'm adding types to vue3's methods function:

```
<script lang="ts">
import {defineComponent} from "vue";

export default defineComponent({
.
.
.
    methods: {
    validatePattern(allowedCharacterRegex: RegExp , unAllowedCharacterRegex: RegExp, event: { preventDefault: () => void; }, value: any) {
      if (allowedCharacterRegex && !allowedCharacterRegex.test(value)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

      if (unAllowedCharacterRegex && unAllowedCharacterRegex.test(value)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

(crying about adding `:RegExp` to `allowedCharacterRegex: RegExp`)
for that code I'm getting  `42:41  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token :` and I don't understand how to prevent it from happening.

my eslint configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
  ],
  overrides: [],
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: "latest",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["vue", "@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {},
};
```

How can I prevent this error from happening?

Comment: Are you adding `lang="ts"` in script tag

Comment: @MoritzRingler doesn't help, happens even if i just do test(text: string) {
...
}

Comment: How do you run eslint? What's config filename? Try to add syntax mistake to config file and make sure it changes anything. It may be not read for some reason

Comment: @EstusFlask i'm running the it by using `eslint --fix --ext .vue .`
my eslint file name is `.eslintrc.js` and if I'm breaking it I'm getting an error (so it's using it right)

Comment: I suppose that you overrode the recommended setup, try to remove at least `plugins` and `parser`. As for `extends`, try `["plugin:vue/vue3-essential", "eslint:recommended", "@vue/typescript/recommended"]`